# Public content from Instagram API

Tags: api, permissions, instagram, instagram-api, hashtag

So I know that you can access your own photos with Instagram API, but why not the public content?

When I try to get permissions for non-sandbox mode, the it tells me,

> This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).

So, I'm guessing that's not possible, but I am able to screen scrape all the public photos...

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1):

yes unfortunately this is the case and yes its extremely frustrating. Beyond a couple of apps the limitations of sandbox make it impossible to develop alot of apps.
My suggestion to you is to use a third parties access token from an access token generator with the scopes you need or go through the labour of getting your app approved